# Mobile Emulators

Tags: android-emulator, ios-simulator, emulation, device-emulation

I want mobile emulators to emulate Android, iPhone and Windows phones. Can`t find emulators anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ***Felice*** said in his answer : `emulators are also available in their respective development sdk.`

- [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- [Iphone emulator](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/)
- [Windows phone emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a6f6adaf-12e3-4b2f-a394-356e2c2fb114&DisplayLang=en)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator is available from [android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually emulator are available once you install the respective developement SDK's